# How to Avoid redeployment of same artifact?

Tags: java, .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In our Client project we have 6 applications , Three Java and three .NET.
We have the code in the same repository in different folders for each app.
The case is that we need to compare the artifacts which is being built with the previous builds to know changes are made or not.
**If changes are made then deploy it
else
Do not deploy it.**
Also, based on the apps. Say if I work on the One Java and one .NET app, I will want to deploy only these two and rest four apps need not be deployed unnecessarily.
How can we achieve this without manual intervention?
Please suggest us with a solution.

Comment: so what stops you to separate the, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set up a build pipeline and corresponding release pipeline for each app.

1. In the build pipeline for each app, you can use the '[**Paths**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths)' key to specify the file paths that can trigger the build pipeline.
2. In the release pipeline for each app, you can try setting up a step to execute the API "[**Builds - Get Changes Between Builds**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to get the changes between the current build and previous build. If no any change made between the two builds, skip the subsequent deployment step.

**[UPDATE]**

> Is there any equivalent API which could provide the difference between two artifacts even if the build manually runs without any changes? So if we do not see any changes in result we could cancel the release pipeline.

To avoid deploying the artifacts that have the same source version, as I mentioned above, you can try using the API "**Builds - Get Changes Between Builds**". In Response body of this API, it will return the array list of commits between the two specified builds.

- If have changes between the two builds, the value of "**count**" property is the number of the commits. And in the "**value**"property (array object), these commits will be listed.

  [image]
- If no any change between the two builds, the value of "**count**" is 0, and "**value**" is an empty array.

  [image]

In your case, you just need to check whether the value of "**count**" is greater than 0. If greater than 0, start the deployment. If equal to 0, skip the deployment to avoid re-deployment.

Comment: Yes, We already suggested the separate pipeline & repo for each app. But they are expecting a way to achieve with same repo for all app and one pipeline for a project type.

Comment: Is there any equivalent API which could provide the difference between two artifacts even if the build manually runs without any changes?
So if we do not see any changes in result we could cancel the release pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Sai, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Bright Ran. We tried to use this API along with Runs API and kind of achieved want we wanted.

Comment: Hi @Sai, glad that the question has been solved. could you please mark my answer as the solution of this topic if it is helpful to you to solve the question? This may be also very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar questions. Of course, you also can post an answer with the summary of the question and your solution, and then mark the answer as the solution. Thanks.